# Evolution calendar how to list all events in calendar. Default view only shows up to month.

Tags: evolution, calendar

I wish i knew how to list all events in calendar. Not only one month selection, but for entire year

[image: Evolution calendar view]
I expect to extend this list from 27.11.2017 to present day. but evolution does not give option for full list without manual scrolling each month at left pane. this behavior is not like Thunderbird lighting calendar i used before

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close my question because it apparently has no solution. I do not want this question commented/voted by people.